# Getting the related information of the selected value in the Drop down without making extra AJAX call

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, drop-down-menu

Lets say I have the following drop down item on the JSP rendered using languageList. When I select a item in the dropdown, respective language is selected.

```
<html:select property="Language" >
<html:optionsCollection name="InputForm" property="languageList"label="label" value="value" />
</html:select>
```

Lets say I have map of  where Country specifies in which that language is spoken. So, country isn't unique but language is. When I select the language I want to display the Country in the UI. I know it can achieved using AJAX calls with language as input arguments. Is there anyway I can achieve the mentioned behavior without the AJAX calls.

I considered having countries in the value,  but my goal is not to just display country on the UI but as well I am making the call to server also with language as the input for further processing. So, I want language in the the value.
Other solution i considered is having combination of country and language as value (UK_ENGLISH). And then I can do the string manipulations, display UK on UI and make the server call with ENGLISH. But this solution seemed bit hacky to me, and was wondering if there is a cleaner approach.

Comment: i would probably set a class using the dropwdown value and CSS to match the map countries with the current class.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. What do you mean ? A small example is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can label your countries in UI with id or class html properties. Then, you render your dropdown list with value populated with comma separated list of corresponding country labels. For example:

```
<select>
  <option value="UK,USA">English</option>
  <option value="France,Canada">French</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Now, if user selects English language, you will take "value" attribute from "option" tag, split it by comma and then select by id/class attribute proper html elements and display them. That's the concept but specifics depend on your exact implementation.

Comment: I considered this but my goal is not to just display UK, USA on the UI. Other than displaying Country on the UI, I am making the call to server with language as the input for further processing. So, I want language in the the value.

Comment: If you are doing ajax call to the server anyway, with language as input, what is the problem to have your server method returns list of countries as well as some other result that you need?

Comment: language will be used as for a call later on the page, and countries are needed to be displayed before that call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to render your map as javascript (or json) object somewhere within your jsp and write a changelistener for your dropdown input.

The creation of the json object can either be done manually or with the help of a framework like jackson. Here is a raw concept of the client implementation.

```
<select id="language" onchange="setCountry()">...</select>
<select id="country">...</select>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var languageMapping =  {
        'German' : ['Germany', 'Swiss', 'Austria' ],
        'English' : ['France', 'Canada'],
        ...
    }

    var setCountry = function() {
        //clean selection
        var countrySelection = document.getElementById("country");
        while (countrySelection.firstChild) {
            countrySelection.removeChild(countrySelection.firstChild);
        }


        var val = document.getElementById("language").value;
        var countryOptions = languageMapping[val];
        //fill selection
        for(var i = 0; i < countryOptions.length; i++) {
            var optionElement = document.createElement("option");
            optionElement.setAttribute("value", countryOptions[i]);
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(countryOptions[i]);
            optionElement.appendChild(textNode);
            countrySelection.appendChild(para);
        }
    }

</script>
```